# How spring Integration(Aggregator) behaves in distributed environment?

Tags: spring-integration

I have a requirement where i want to aggregate messages using Aggregator Pattern based on the correlation_id but i think i might face problem in distributed environment e.g having multiple server nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a shared message group store and shared lock registry so that all instances can see the aggregation group but only one can update a group at the same time.

See [Managing State in an Aggregator: MessageGroupStore](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#reaper) - JDBC, Redis Mongo etc. and [Lock Registry](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#_lockregistry) - Zookeeper, Redis etc.